# creating application on developer facebook account

Tags: ios7, account

I am try to creat the application on developer facebook site but i get an error 
"Creating the app failed
Please use your personal account to create this app To use a different name for testing, create the app with your personal account and then create a test account . If you received this message in error, please submit on appeal ."
please help. Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolve the that problem.
Actually this error is occur due to **firewalls** or **restrictions on some web sites**.
After removing that **Firewalls** and creating application from **Different IP Addressess** i did not get this error again.